# The Cyclomatic Complexity of this function is 11 which is greater than 10 authorized

Tags: typescript, angular6

```
if ((['ALL', ''].includes(this.accountnumber.value) ? true : ele.accountnumber === this.accountnumber.value) &&
        (['ALL', ''].includes(this.description.value) ? true : ele.description === this.description.value) &&
        (['ALL', ''].includes(this.country.value) ? true : ele.country === this.country.value) &&
        (!this.entryDate ? true : (this.entryDate === dateEntry)) && 
        (!this.editedDate ? true : (this.editedDate === dateEdited))) {
        return true;
      }
```

Comment: That's rather a statement than a question. Yes, the complexity is too big and the code is unreadable/unmaintainable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes it's better to write more code in order to understand better what's going on.

A first quick change would be to expand your `if` content like :

Note that the ternary is not mandatory. A simple `||` operator will have the same effect.

**PS**: Because I haven't thinked about the why you are doing what you are doing I've used bad variable naming. If you reuse the following, change them and add comments about what you are trying to achieve.

```
const isA = [
 'ALL',
 '',
].includes(this.accountnumber.value) || ele.accountnumber === this.accountnumber.value;

const isB = [
  'ALL',
  '',
].includes(this.description.value) || ele.description === this.description.value;

const isC = [
  'ALL',
  '',
 ].includes(this.country.value) || ele.country === this.country.value;

const isD = !this.entryDate || this.entryDate === dateEntry;

const isE = !this.editedDate || this.editedDate === dateEdited;

if (isA && isB && isC && isD && isE) {
  return true;
}
```

---

Expanding also make it even more obvious that some code is duplicated.

```
function checkCond(key, obj, arr = [
  'ALL',
  '',
]) {
  return arr.includes(this[key].value) || obj[key] === this[key].value; 
}

const isA = checkCond('accountnumber', ele);
const isB = checkCond('description', ele);
const isB = checkCond('country', ele);

const isD = !this.entryDate || this.entryDate === dateEntry;

const isE = !this.editedDate || this.editedDate === dateEdited;

if (isA && isB && isC && isD && isE) {
  return true;
}
```

Even further :

```
function checkCond(key, obj, arr = [
  'ALL',
  '',
]) {
  return arr.includes(this[key].value) || obj[key] === this[key].value; 
}

const conditions = [
  checkCond('accountnumber', ele),
  checkCond('description', ele),
  checkCond('country', ele),

  !this.entryDate || this.entryDate === dateEntry,
  !this.editedDate || this.editedDate === dateEdited,
];

if (conditions.every(x => x)) {
  return true;
}
```